# Convert this kind of hex string to a NSData/NSString

Tags: c, cocoa, nsstring, hex, nsdata

I have this hex string:

```
\x5c30\x3032\x5f5c\x3337\x345c\x3334\x366f\x5c32\x3633\x5c30\x3136\x5c32\x3132\x5c32\x3234\x4e5c\x3236\x335c\x3231\x335c\x3337\x355c\x3335\x315c\x3232\x365c\x3337
```

How could I convert it to a NSString or NSData? I though of using C methods, but I'm not experienced in C :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like Unicode characters (specifically, CJK ideographs) to me.

Use an [NSScanner](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003726) to scan the string. Scan up to a backslash, and [add whatever you scanned to a mutable string](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableString_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableString/appendString%3a). Then, scan the backslash and throw it away, and then scan the x and throw that away.

Then, scan four single characters, which will be the digits (NSScanner doesn't have a method to scan a single character, so you will need to get them yourself using `characterAtIndex:` and then adjust the scanner's scan location accordingly). Perform the appropriate conversion of the hexadecimal digit characters to numbers and the math to assemble a single number from them, and you will have the code point (character value) represented by the escape sequence. Add that single character to your string.

Repeat that until you run out of input string, and you will have converted the input string with all its escape sequences into a string with the unescaped characters.